# Rolling back a gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber

---

Ok, I changed my gem file

cucumber (1.0.6)

```
  builder (>= 2.1.2)
  diff-lcs (>= 1.1.2)
  gherkin (~> 2.4.18)
  json (>= 1.4.6)
  term-ansicolor (>= 1.0.6)
cucumber-rails (1.0.6)
  capybara (>= 1.1.1)
  cucumber (>= 1.0.6)
  nokogiri (>= 1.5.0)
```

But a web_steps.rb file doesn't appear? Do I need to run anything in the command line to get it to show up?

---

Gemfile:

cucumber (1.1.7)

```
  builder (>= 2.1.2)
  diff-lcs (>= 1.1.2)
  gherkin (~> 2.8.0)
  json (>= 1.4.6)
  term-ansicolor (>= 1.0.6)
cucumber-rails (1.2.1)
  capybara (>= 1.1.2)
  cucumber (>= 1.1.3)
  nokogiri (>= 1.5.0)
```

Thanks for the answers! But I am now getting the error?

You have requested:
  cucumber = 1.0.6

The bundle currently has cucumber locked at 1.1.7.
Try running `bundle update cucumber`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can install a specific version of a gem by using:

```
gem install <gem> -v=<version>
```

e.g.

```
gem install cucumber -v=1.1.4
```

Then you specify in your gemfile, that you want this specific version:

```
gem 'cucumber', '1.1.4'
```

This way your rails app should use the version you want.

Concerning your Gemfile.lock problem. Try using

```
bundle update
```

Or delete your Gemfile.lock (it will be rebuild automatically when you try to start your rails app).

Answer (score 0):

Add to your Gemfile or chenge current entry to:
`gem 'cucumber', '1.1.1'`
where 1.1.1 is the cucumber version you want to use. Next run `bundle`.

Comment: You have requested:
  cucumber = 1.0.6

The bundle currently has cucumber locked at 1.1.7.
Try running `bundle update cucumber`

Comment: How do I remove a 1.1.7 and reload it with 1.0.6?

Answer (score 0):

Change it in your gem file. So assuming you want to use version 1.5, you would have

```
gem 'cucumber', '1.5'
```

The next thing would be to install the gem by running `bundle install` from the terminal

If this is because of the web_steps.rb file that got removed from cucumber, the you can add the following to your gemfile

```
gem "cucumber-rails-training-wheels", :group => :test
```

However make sure you read [THIS](http://aslakhellesoy.com/post/11055981222/the-training-wheels-came-off)